# scrollable homepage doesn't scroll well

Tags: flutter, dart, android-widget

```
Flexible(
 child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: ref.snapshots(),
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasError){
          return Center(
          child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
        );
       }
      //here what widget should i add
     return Scrollbar(
        child: GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 15,
              crossAxisSpacing: 15,
              childAspectRatio: 2/3,
     ),
```

i don't know why the scrollable on homepage can't work well start from the gridView i can't touch on that section to perform the scroll action

Comment: do you have any scroll widget in parent widgets?

Comment: body: Scrollbar(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: location,
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabled: true,
                        hintText: 'Your Current Location ...',

Comment: on the body i declare scrollbar widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put two scroll view inside each other that happened, you need to disable second scroll view 's physics, try change your code to this:

```
 Scrollbar(
    child: GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // <--- add this
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 15,
        crossAxisSpacing: 15,
        childAspectRatio: 2 / 3,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two scrollable widgets together, so they're clashing. so set `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` on your `GridView`.

```dart
Scrollbar(
      child: GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), 
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: are you field in geofencing? may i ask about that topic? cause i don't really undestand how to implement

Comment: @peanut I'm not even sure what that means :)

Comment: okay never mind. thank you for your response :) . but can you help me how to solve the "null check operator used on a null value" . i got confuse cause it just glimpse appear on the screen but it still can display the images. what should i do?

Comment: @peanut That's a completely _separate_ problem. Consider closing this question by  marking it [as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and ask a _new_ question on StackOverflow.